# How to define the first row number of a Named Range? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script Editor, I am trying to identify how to use getRow() or equivalent statement to be able to output the row number of the first row in a Named Range.

For example, I have a named range **showHide** from C4:C10. What would I use to output "4" since that is the first row of my range?

Answer (score 1):

`getRow`, `getValue` and similar functions applied to ranges always output the top left cell's content.

So for you this does the job:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("showHide").getRow();
```